# copying address space of a function using memcpy

Tags: function, pointers, memcpy

i have defined the fun pointer type as

```
typedef void (*fn)(void)
```

declared a pointer variable : 
    fn var = NULL;
have written a small function 
    void fun(void){}
Now, i want to copy the address space of function fun into var variable using memcpy. I am trying this :
    memcpy(var, &fun, sizeof(fn))

But, when i printing the value of var it is showing up the garbage or negative value, and invoking the function from var is resulting into segmentation fault.
pls help, where am i wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably `memcpy(&var,&fun,sizeof(fn))`, or it would fail instantly with `var` initialized to `NULL`.

The `memcpy` above is copying first bytes of `fun`'s *code* to `var`, which is not what you want (not that it's a defined behavior by any standard, it's just how it probably happens to misbehave on your OS/compiler).

Use just `var = fun;` instead.

If you're determined to play with `memcpy` (for fun or learning), you'll have to get a variable containing a pointer to function first, not just a *value* of that pointer:

```
fn var1 = fun;
fn var2 = NULL;
memcpy(&var2,&var1,sizeof(fn));
var2();
```